# Access file on a separate machine using Python

Tags: python, bash

I currently need to access files on another machine and also execute bash commands on that machine in Python. I was wondering how I would do that. Is there anything in either the standard library? If there isn't is Paramiko what I'm looking for?

The specific Bash command I am looking to run is:

journalctl writes some string info to stdout. I need to pipe it to a file on my machine, or copy the file under a different name (scp? sftp?).

```
journalctl > /some_directory/some_file_name.txt
```

Comment: If you want a python script to log into a remote machine and run a bunch of commands you could look into [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/)

Comment: or (if it's mostly system administation you are trying to achieve): http://docs.ansible.com/

Comment: Have you tried using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module to run your command?  For example, you could run the command `ssh machine '/path/to/journalctl > /path/to/output.txt'`.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easiest to use the 'sh' library found at

https://amoffat.github.io/sh/

or

```
pip install sh
```

And then just call ssh, your remote commands, etc.

Comment: Even though link contains the answer, you should write it here such that even if links don't work in future, it should not deteriorate your answer, and future reader can understand it without the help of link. Link should only be used to strengthen your answer and not as an answer.

Comment: Very well, I've fixed it so there is some distant hope of use in case of the link-eating zombie apocalypse.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain what your solution does.  It just points the OP to an external resource and says "use this".

Comment: The question specifically asks for a library useful in solving the problem. The suggested library exactly 'facilitating shell-like scripting in python'.